# In python how can I take input from user and jump to a different line after taking input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, goto

am new to python and was working on the following code (program to find average)

```
sum=0
for i in range(1,9999):
    n=int(input("Enter your number: "))
    i+=1
    sum=n+sum
    a=input("Do you want to add more (Y/N): ")
    if a=="Y" or a=="y":
        continue
    elif a=="N" or a=="n":
        break
    else:
        print("Error: Incorrect choice")
i-=1
avg=sum/i
print(avg)
```

All good, but if the user inputs "Incorrect choice" how can I make it jump to the "if statement" where it asks the user again whether he/she wants to add more number? In structured programming I think "goto" or "label" can be used, but python is object oriented, how can I make it work here. Please advice.

Comment: There's various forms of [control-flow](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) in Python. I suggest you read up on those first. They are part of the building blocks of Python. There is no "Goto" in Python, just the control flow statements which include while, for, function calls, generators, and conditionals.

Comment: As far as your program is concerned, you can add the input statement and the Y/N checks into a nested `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

there are several way
you can use "while"

```
while a not in ["Y","y","N","n"]:
    a=input("Do you want to add more (Y/N): ")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot azro, am able to understand this, but can't think of a way to add that in the above code.